# Adding Manipulation Components via C# Script Only Works in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm attempting to dynamically add an FBX model into a scene and add the following components to the child objects of the main GameObject created from the FBX model:

MeshCollider (I Add a mesh to this using the sharedMesh variable)

ManipulationHandler

NearInteractionGrabbable

When I test the functionality in Unity it works flawlessly. When I deploy to the HoloLens 2 only the objects that wouldn't require "convex = true" are working.

It makes me feel like setting convex = true isn't working when deployed on the hololens 2.

Here's my code for your reference on how I'm getting things to work:

```
void Start()
    {
        //Grab object from Resources/Objects using provided unique identifier
        //I'm instantiating like this because I'm setting the parent to another GameObject in the original code and I got errors if I didn't do it this way
        GameObject go = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Objects/" + objectId));
        //Loop through child objects of model
        for (int i = 0; i < go.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            AddManipulationComponents(go.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
        }
    }

    void AddManipulationComponents(GameObject item)
    {
        //Get MeshFilter so I can set the mesh of it to the sharedMesh of the MeshCollider
        MeshFilter meshFilter = item.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        //Only Add MeshCollider components if there's a mesh on the object.
        if (meshFilter != null)
        {
            Mesh mesh = item.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
            if (mesh != null)
            {
                //Add MeshCollider
                MeshCollider collider = item.EnsureComponent<MeshCollider>();
                //A lot of components are curved and need convex set to false
                collider.convex = true;
                //Add NearInteractionGrabbable
                item.EnsureComponent<NearInteractionGrabbable>();
                //Add ManipulationHandler
                item.EnsureComponent<ManipulationHandler>();
                //Set mesh to MeshCollider
                collider.sharedMesh = mesh;
            }
        }
        //If current component has children, then loop through those.
        if (item.transform.childCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.transform.childCount; i++)
            {
                AddManipulationComponents(item.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works when I run it through Unity, but when I build it and deploy to the HoloLens 2 it doesn't completely work. By that I mean there's only 3 or 4 child objects that actually work and they happen to be flat objects. It makes me think the "convex" variable in MeshCollider is not behaving as I'd hope.

Anyone have a fix for this?

Here's a photo of it working through unity (I clipped out proprietary information):

[image: SnapShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing the FBX you need to select the checkbox for "Read/Write"

[image]

I enabled that and made sure to export all materials as well.

Answer (score 0):

Convex mesh colliders are limited to 255 triangles, perhaps this is why its not working?

Comment: It works if I manually add it in unity and deploy to the hololens. It only doesn't work if I use C# to set it. And it may not be the convex thing. Something else might be breaking it that I'm not aware of.

Comment: are you using triggers for your collisions? if so make sure you set isTrigger to true

Comment: I appreciate your input. I'm not using triggers. My goal is to just be able to grab the objects and manipulate them. Thus adding ManipulationHandler, NearInteractionGrabbable, and MeshCollider. Is there anything else I would need to add that I'm missing?

Comment: can you put a screenshot of those three components from the ones in the scene?

Comment: i mean like the components of the inspector, how they are set up when they are working

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the question. Let me know what you think.